# Asp.net Gridview substring using Bind()

Tags: asp.net, substring, bind

I am showing data in grid view but some fields contain large data(couple of lines). I want to show only some part of it in the grid not the all data.
i found some example(substring) using 'Eval' but how to do using Bind(). Please help

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="vDepartment">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vDepartment") %>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label377" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vDepartment") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Ternary Operator to check the length of `vDepartment` and use `Substring` when it exceeds the maximum length.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label377" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vDepartment").ToString().Length > 25 ? Eval("vDepartment").ToString().Substring(0, 25) : Eval("vDepartment") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the quick help which is working fine. can we do it using Bind()

Comment: No, it does not work with `Bind`. If you are having problems you could try `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "vDepartment").ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the help.